# scipy.stats.rv_continuous distribution with gap: problems with support?

Tags: python, inheritance, scipy

I need several continuous distributions with gaps in them to fit some data, and am subclassing `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` for that purpose.  Below is an example for a uniform distribution with a gap in it.  The distribution is flat between `s0` and `l`, and between `h` and `s1`.

```
from scipy.stats import *

class gapF_gen(rv_continuous):
    ''' Class for a flat distribution with a gap in it
    s0, s1: bounds of support
    l, h: gap
    s0 < l < h < s1
    '''
    def _argcheck(self, s0, s1, l, h):  return (s0 < l < h < s1)
        
    def _get_support(self, s0, s1, l, h):   return s0, s1
    
    def _pdf(self, x, s0, s1, l, h):
        if (s0 <= x <= l) or (h <= x <= s1): return 1 / (s1 - h + l - s0)   
        else: return 0

gapF = gapF_gen(name='gapF')

bf = gapF(s0=-2.6, s1=4.77, l=-1.3, h=3.5)
print(bf.pdf(-2.8))  # OK
print(bf.pdf([-23.8, 3.8, 2.6, 6.9, 77.9])) # Not OK
```

I have defined `_pdf` to check if the value is zero or not.  This works when passing scalar values to the automatically generated `pdf`, but when lists are passed to `pdf`, things don't work because of the range check:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

On the other hand, if I rename my function to override ```pdf``, then for scalars I get the error:

`TypeError: _parse_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 's0'`

Are there any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply that you cannot do `s0 <= x <= l0` with x being a numpy array (try it!). Instead, use bitwise and : `(s0 <= x) & (x <= l0)`  . Or, if you like it more verbose, use `np.logical_and`.

And BTW, you should not override `pdf`. Sub classes only implement the underscored methods: _pdf, _cdf etc.

Comment: Thanks @ev-br for your response, but your suggestion doesn't work for me, alas.  Here is an even simpler example that fails for me:  def test(x, y): return 1 if (x & y) else 0
print(test(1, 1))
print(test(np.array([1,1]), np.array([1,0])))

Comment: of course it does not: `np.array([True, False]) & np.array([True, True])` evaluates to `array([ True, False])` --- it's an array, so it cannot be used in a python `if`. Use `np.all` or `np.any` for array -> scalar reduction and np.where for elementwise decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ev-bre's hints, the following works:

```
from scipy.stats import *

class gapF_gen(rv_continuous):
    ''' Class for a flat distribution with a gap in it
    s0, s1: bounds of support
    l, h: gap
    s0 < l < h < s1
    '''
    def _argcheck(self, s0, s1, l, h):  return (s0 < l < h < s1)
        
    def _get_support(self, s0, s1, l, h):   return s0, s1
    
    def _pdf(self, x, s0, s1, l, h):
        return np.where(((s0 <= x) & (x <= l)) | ((h <= x) & (x <= s1)), 1 / (s1 - h + l - s0), 0)

gapF = gapF_gen(name='gapF')

bf = gapF(s0=-2.2, s1=4.77, l=-1.3, h=3.5)
print(bf.pdf(-2.8))
print(bf.pdf([-23.8, 3.8, 2.6, 6.9, 77.9, -2.1]))
```